# How do I authenticate with biometrics on every activity centrally

Tags: android, process, biometrics, central

I am looking to authenticate the user using face ID / fingerprint / passcode every time an activity is reloaded (think minimising the app and reopening, not from just opening a new activity), now there are quite a few activities in my app... The trouble I am having thus far is that I need to use the context of each activity to display the biometrics popup

**So ideally I am looking for a standard central way of doing this, is there such a process in Android for this?**

*- Just to mention, I don't need to know how to do the biometrics*

Comment: Perhaps there should not be multiple activities in the app. Instead, have one (or few) activities, using fragments or composables for individual screens.

Comment: Is Interitance still an option here? Why don't you put logic related for each Activity into the BaseAuthActivity?

Comment: Create a BaseActivity and extend All of your activities from BaseActivity. then define the authentication method in your BaseActivity.